# Gradient of a multiple variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

[image]

I am a bit confused here. This question from Advance calculus by Folland, asks me to calculate prime of H(x,y) but its a multiple variable function and when we derivate a multiple variable function we calculate the gradient vector as far as I know but how am I supposed to find the prime of H ? is there some mistake in the question or am I missing something here? any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: It should be a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: $H'$ will be a $2\times 2$ matrix which will be product of the Jacobian matrices of the other two, but with $a,b,c$ plugged in after the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Folland's notation we have

$$G'(a,b,c) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+c}} & \frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+c}} \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

$$F'(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} y & x \\ 2xy^2 & 2x^2y \\ 3x^2y^3 & 3x^3y^2 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

Which means

$$H'(x,y) = G'(xy,(xy)^2,(xy)^3)\cdot F'(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} y+2xy^2 & x + 2x^2y \\ \frac{2xy^2+3x^2y^3}{2\sqrt{(xy)^2+(xy)^3}} & \frac{2x^2y+3x^3y^2}{2\sqrt{(xy)^2+(xy)^3}} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Be careful with absolute values when simplifying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i know how to find the gradient. maybe my question wasn't clear but i meant to know when could i say the derivative of H ( a multiple variable function) is equal to the gradient of H ?

Comment: @mulaan22 the distinction you bring up only exists when the topic is introduced to calculus 3 students (for good reason, there is a need to separate differentiability from antidifferentiability as concepts in higher dimensions). In this context there is no need to throw around different words for a $1\times 1$ map (single variable derivative), a $1\times n$ map (scalar gradient), or an $n\times n$ map (change of variables Jacobian). They are all $m\times n$ maps which have partial derivative entries. Although typically the notation $DF$ or $JF$ is used instead of prime because they're matrices